# bluetooth connection: host is down

Tags: 17.10, bluetooth, headset, blueman

I'm on ubuntu 17.10 and trying to connect my bluetooth headset QCY-Q19. 
it's able to pair but whenever I try to connect I get this error `Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Host is down` 
sometimes it connects for few seconds and then fails with the same error.

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Comment: no, I changed my laptop recently and it worked just fine.

Comment: Restart your computer, i have had this problem and i suspect bluetooth drivers are to blame

Answer (score 6):

I've had this exact same issue before. What I ended up doing was unpairing the device, resetting it up, which solved the connection issue. After that, I saved it as a trusted device and so far haven't had issues since.

Answer (score 1):

You may also see this error if the device you're trying to connect to is already paired to something else.  For example, my headphones will latch onto my phone if it has Bluetooth on, causing my Ubuntu desktop to fail to connect.

Comment: Was actually the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in 20.04. I unpaired it from my phone and issue resolved.